# How to fetch extension attributes from Magento checkout page

Tags: checkout, attributes

I added custom address field in magento checkout and i want to save it to sale_order and qoute table. I follow this tutorial on how to add and save custom field in magento checkout.
https://navnitviradiya.com/magento-2-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-checkout-page/
but ihaving a trouble fetching the extension attribute. any idea what's wrong?